# MQTT shared subscription

Tags: mqtt

With a MQTT shared subscription, the message on the subscirbed topic would only be sent to **one** of the subscribing clients. Then, how the other clients of the group receive the message as they also subscribe to the same topic?

Comment: https://emqx.medium.com/introduction-to-mqtt-5-0-protocol-shared-subscription-4c23e7e0e3c1

Comment: If the server randomly select one in all shared subscription sessions to publish messages, how the others receive the message?

Comment: You do not have to use shared subscriptions if you don't want the capability it provides...

Comment: I asked the question for clarification only. You seem have some misunderstanding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With a MQTT shared subscription, the message on the subscribed topic would only be sent to one of the subscribing clients.

Correct. With a normal ([non‑shared](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901249)) subscription the messages are sent to ALL subscribers; with [shared](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901250) subscriptions they are sent to ONE subscriber.

Prior to the introduction of shared subscriptions it was difficult to handle situations where you want multiple servers (for fault tolerance, load balancing etc) but only want to process each message once. Shared subscriptions provide a simple way of accomplishing this.

> Then, how the other clients of the group receive the message as they also subscribe to the same topic?

If they are subscribing to the same shared subscription (with the same `ShareName`) then only one will receive the message; this is by design. If you want them all to receive the message then don't use a shared subscription. Alternatively you can establish multiple subscriptions (so all subscribers receive the message but only one processes it - but note the "could") as per [the spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901250):

> If a Client has a Shared Subscription and a Non‑shared Subscription and a message matches both of them, the Client will receive a copy of the message by virtue of it having the Non‑shared Subscription. A second copy of the message will be delivered to one of the subscribers to the Shared Subscription, and this could result in a second copy being sent to this Client.

Comment: I am reading [link](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqttv5-shared-subscriptions/) about shared subscription. I don't understand how shared subscription works. Why only one of the clients subscribe to $share/movies/test receive message? In my uderstanding, clients subscribe the same shared topic will receive the message but it is not...I think I still not clear about the meaning of shared subsription. Could you further explain how it works? Thanks!

Comment: With standard subscriptions every subscriber receives each message. With shared subscriptions only one of the subscriber's receives each message. This is by design (see the spec). Im not sure which part of this is not clear?

Comment: Because I think message should be delivered to all subscribed clients. If only one of the subscriber receive the message, then what is the purpose of choosing this design from the perspective of a subscriber? They may not receive the message they want. Thanks!

Comment: Shared subscriptions allow for the event where message are only processed once yet still allowing for multiple clients to be available to do that processing, this could be because there are more messages than can be processed by one client or where redundancy is required

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting bug in Java Paho (1.2.5) client that prevents working with shared topics that contains wildcards (`#`, `+`) https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/827

Long story short, this will not work:

```java
mqttClient.subscribe("$share/group/some_topic/#", 1, (topic, message) -> System.out.println(topic));
```

instead it's required to use callbacks:

```java
mqttClient.subscribe("$share/group/some_topic/#", 1);
mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(final Throwable cause) {

    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(final String topic, final MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(topic);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(final IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

    }
});
```

Comment: While an interesting aside, this doesn't actually answer the question asked.

Comment: This question shows up high in Google if you type `java mqtt shared subscription not working` so I thought adding this answer will help other ppl

Comment: @MAGx2: Typo there. It should be '$share' instead of '$shared'